# Magento2 add order status to attribute class <tr> in admin orders list

Tags: magento2

I want to get different colors orders (table row) in the admin list of orders, depending on its status. I think the simplest is to add a class to the status of the  when rendering a table of orders and the corresponding CSS code, but I have no idea how to do it.

I have:

```
<tr class="data-row" data-bind="css: {'_odd-row': $index % 2}" data-repeat-index="0">
```

need:

```
<tr class="data-row pending" data-bind="css: {'_odd-row': $index % 2}" data-repeat-index="0">
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Find answer. Modify vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/listing.html

```
<tr class="data-row" repeat="foreach: rows, item: '$row'" css="[rows[$index].status]: true, '_odd-row': $index % 2">
```

I'm still waiting for a better solution